# The Windy Tales favorites

Tags: wordplay, lateral-thinking

Just another day at the office at Windy Tales inc.
With some delay the twins had mixed their favorites. Unfortunately, the mixes got mixed up.

> HE LEFT MY PAPER NET AND SAT RIVALLED ON THE ICE CUE THAT DREAM ESKIMO WINS A CRASH CINEMA CLUE DIAL TWO MOO POACH SQUID

Can you figure out the names of their favorites?

P.S.: Lady Twines pointed out that alphabetically A(2), C(7), C(5), M(2), M(6), M(5), P(2), P(3), Q(8), S(2) was actually her favorite.

Hint:

> A good place to start here is to think about (based on the tags to this puzzle) what these "mixes" might be a reference to and how that could change the name of the company.

Comment: On account of the tag `lateral-thinking` : could the answer be 'Yes' or 'No'?

Comment: Yes, it could be, but no, it isn't :P

Comment: @Levieux- __"how that could change the name of the company"__ I didn't get it. And Lady Twines or Lady Twins? :-/

Comment: @Techidiot: Lady Twines. She is probably one of the Delay twins.

Comment: Hmm.. Yes. I thought it was a typo.

Comment: No typo, Lady Twines and the "delay twins" all work for Windy Tales, a.k.a. ...

Comment: @Levieux-  aka .. ***Divine Tales*** :-/

Comment: @Techidiot: No, aka the Daily Newts or the Daylit News... `:)`

Comment: @MOehm-  Oh anagrams. That would be quite a work to apply anagrams to so many words up there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The common theme behind the mixes is ...

> **Walt Disney**, which is an anagram of *Windy Tales*, *Lady Twines* or *Twins* (with) *delay*.

I guess that the favourites are ...

> ... protagonists of Walt Disney films, namely:
>
>  AND DIAL – **Aladdin**
>  THE ICE CRASH – **Cheshire Cat**
>  CLUE RIVALLED – **Cruella de Vil**
>  THAT DREAM – **Mad Hatter**
>  CINEMA LEFT – **Maleficent**
>  MY CUE ESKIMO – **Mickey Mouse**
>  PAPER NET – **Peter Pan**
>  POACH ON SAT – **Pocahontas**
>  SQUID A MOO – **Quasimodo**
>  WINS TWO HE – **Snow White**

Lady Twines' favourite ...

> ... is made up of the *i* th letter of each of the solutions starting with the corresponding letters. This is also a hint that there was one solution starting with A, two starting with C and so on. The list is sorted alphabetically by character name:
>
>  A(2) → L (A**l**addin)
>  C(7) → R (Cheshi**r**e Cat)
>  C(5) → L (Crue**l**la de Vil)
>  M(2) → A (M**a**d Hatter)
>  M(6) → I (Malef**i**cent)
>  M(5) → E (Mick**e**y Mouse)
>  P(2) → E (P**e**ter Pan)
>  P(3) → C (Po**c**ahontas)
>  Q(8) → D (Quasimo**d**o)
>  S(2) → N (S**n**ow White)
>
>  Unscrambling the letters LRLAIEECDN leads to **Cinderella**.

Comment: +1. I haven't watched half of them. :) Also, not sure how it was supposed to be solved. :D Too tough. Well done

Comment: @Techidiot: The tough part was to find out about Walt Disney. Most anagram tools fail here, but [Chambers Word Wizard](http://chambers.co.uk/puzzles/word-wizard/), which has other drawbacks, knows about Walt Disney. I recognised only Snow White and Pocahontas before resorting to [the Interwebs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Disney_animated_universe_characters).

Comment: Oh I see. So there are anagram solvers for finding proper nouns as well. Great. Bookmarked! :)

Comment: @MOehm: well done! Only the Lady Twines' favorite is not quite correct yet, as you identified yourself. Keep in mind that her list was ordered alphabetically ;)

Comment: @Levieux: Okay, got it. (It ws actually one of the Characters I knew and expected to find it in the list. By the way, my list is sorted, too, which helped.)

Comment: Nice, that's it!